# What old sci-fi film is the source of this Hotels.com ad clip featuring a fire-breathing monster?

Tags: story-identification, movie, advertisements

Youtube keeps giving me ads for Hotels.com, which feature a few seconds of what looks like it must be a scene from an old sci-fi film:

[image: screenshot of fire-breathing monster]
[image: second screenshot when it's just breathing smoke]

There's a giant seal-like monster, on top of a pile of rocks, breathing fire and roaring. It's extremely distinctive and kind of intriguing, even though it's so crappily made, like something from 1970s Doctor Who, before the special effects era.

**What film or TV show does this come from?** (If any. But surely Hotels.com wouldn't bother to make something like this just for an ad, rather than getting whatever necessary permission to use some old film footage.)

I couldn't find a link to an actual Youtube video of the exact ad I'm getting, but I did find a [Danish version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5F6Raas3SF4) which features the same clip.

Comment: If you're wondering whether this should be on-topic or not: [relevant meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7343/31394).

Comment: [The clip](https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/video/monster-exhaling-fire-at-top-of-mountain-stock-video-footage/102343344) is available on getty images with the caption: _"MS TU TD Monster exhaling fire at top of mountain - stock video"_. It is credited to "Warner Bros. Studios" so maybe it's from a film or TV show but I'm not sure.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - MS = Medium Shot. TD = Tilting Down. TU = Tilting Up

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - The video is also tagged "1966 videos"

Comment: It could be so crappily made on purpose... I find it very funny, not sure if it was meant to be terrifying. It's from an old film indeed, but not sure about sci-fi - could be some kind of self-made monster competition from the 80s. It's **too** crappily made for a colour film.

Comment: https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/search/filmmaker?assettype=film&excludenudity=true&family=creative&filmdefinition=hd&filmmaker=warner%20bros.%20studios&imagetechnique=color&license=rr&phrase=godzilla&sort=mostpopular - Some other clips posted by the same studio and much the same time

Comment: I'm relieved to know that this time it's not some famous thing which you watchers of popular sci-fi films would immediately find obvious :-)

Comment: @RandalThor - I have my suspicions that it's test footage.

Comment: I thought it was Katla from «Brødena Lejonhjärta», but after doublechecking I see that i missremembered what she looked like.

Comment: @epsben - Lol. It's not far off https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1y5Viz2EsA

Comment: In the info box for the clip, it says "Release info: Not released", which makes me believe it is of unused special effects that were cut from a movie - or maybe the movie was never finished.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I'd still be interested to know what film, if possible, even if it's a deleted scene or an unfinished project.

Comment: @JohnRennie I didn't add the [tag:movie] tag originally because I wasn't sure if it's from a film or TV series. From the answer below, it actually seems to be the latter.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I believe this clip is from the Warner Bros production of [Tarzan](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060033/?ref_=tt_ov_inf), which ran from 1966 to 1968.

The episode in question was [Track of the Dinosaur](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0718000/), and I believe it first aired on 6th Jan 1967.

The synopsis on IMDb reads like this:

> Tarzan and Jai visit the Katonga people, finding them in fear of a strange creature in the hills. Tarzan finds an old foe Curt and his wife Diana also among the tribe, he seeks to find out the truth about the fire breathing "monster."

Thanks to *Clara Diaz Sanchez* for this screenshot showing the 'monster' taken directly from the episode:

[image: Episode screenshot]

Thanks again to *Clara Diaz Sanchez*, we can all watch [the actual scene in question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WKKgqD5bos).

This looks like the same clip of the monster itself, but with a more 'full' foreground than we can see in OPs clip.

I have included a couple of screenshots from this episode I found on [scificfanhorrormedia.blogspot](https://scificfanhorrormedia.blogspot.com/2021/06/ron-elys-tarzan-17-track-of-dinosaur.html?m=1), which clearly show the same 'monster' in different parts of the episode.

This looks like it was taken from the same scene as OPs clip, or maybe just after:

[image: This looks like it was taken from the same scene]

Another view of the 'monster' from an earlier scene:

[image: another view from an earlier scene]

A view of the 'monster' and Tarzan in the same scene:

[image: monster and Tarzan]

The date and copyright ownership matches up with the clip found by *TheLethalCarrot*.

This all leads me to believe that this clip was definitely filmed for the episode in question, but it was either a test clip for effects or was cut from the final release.

Comment: Hmm. Surprisingly hard to track down, even through (ahem) slightly illicit channels

Comment: According to [this episode guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarzan_(1966_TV_series)#Season_1:_1966–67), "Track of the Dinosaur" should be on [Tarzan - Season One: Part Two](https://www.amazon.com/Tarzan-Season-One-Part-Discs/dp/B007K7IASA/) which collects the last 16 episodes of the first season (and the amazon description mentions an episode about 'phantom dinosaurs').

Comment: It's so close it *can't* just be coincidence..

Comment: Agreed, this has got to be it. Nice sleuthing!

Comment: Yes, this is it. I've put a screen grab from the episode at https://ibb.co/VBrT7QF

Comment: For further enjoyment, I've put the entire sequence on YouTube, https://youtu.be/0WKKgqD5bos  I think the video has been letterboxed for the DVD release though, so some of the picture may be missing above the monster.

Comment: It is definitely it. If you look at the clip at 0:31 you can even recognize the exact rocks in front of the dino in the picture. 
https://youtu.be/0WKKgqD5bos?t=31